# show that the variance of the estimator is minimized by,,,

Tags: self-study, inference

> Suppose that X and Y are independent Poisson distributed values with
>   means 2θ and θ, respectively. Consider the combined estimator of θ˜θ =
>   k1X + k2Y
>
> (a) Find the condition on k1 and k2 such that ˜θ is an unbiased
>   estimator of θ.
>   (b) For ˜θ unbiased, show that the variance of the estimator is minimized by taking k1 = 1/3 and k2 = 1/3.
>   (c) Given observations x and y find the maximum likelihood estimate of θ and hence show that ˜θ is also the maximum likelihood estimator.

I understand part (a), k1+k2=1; on part 2 I am stuck getting the variance; on part (c) I'm all good.

Comment: got part (a) , k1+k2=1 , part 2 stuck getting variance, part (c) im all gud

Comment: Because the tag has been added & our policy is now met, I am retracting my close vote. This Q should stay open.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to recheck your answer to part (a). For example, you could have $k_1 = k_2 = \frac{1}{2}$, but does $E[.5X + .5Y] = \theta$?

For part (b), what do you know about the variance of a Poisson random variable? What happens to variance of a random variable when you multiply by a constant? What is the variance of the sum of independent random variables?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @js279. I appreciate that you seem to understand our policy for `[self-study]` questions & are helping the OP by providing hints to nudge them along.

Answer (score 0):

The estimator is $\tilde{\theta}=k_1X+k_2Y$, meaning the variance is

$\begin{eqnarray*}
Var(\tilde{\theta}) &=& Var(k_1X+k_2Y) \\
&=& Var(k_1X)+Var(k_2Y) \\
&=& k_1^2\cdot Var(X)+k_2^2\cdot Var(Y) \\
&=& k_1^2\cdot 2\theta+k_2^2\cdot \theta \\
\end{eqnarray*}$

Since we seek to minimize this function, perhaps take the derivative with respect to $\theta$ (as $\theta$ is the quantity changing), set the derivative equal to zero, and solve for $k_1$ and $k_2$.  Make sure to check the double derivative to ensure that the minimum is truly a minimum.

Comment: You ought to emphasize that there is a restriction on $(k_1,k_2)$.

Comment: ohhhh, kk thankyou matt brems , i pretty much had the answer already